# List all fields with the feature they are defined in

Tags: entities, features

I'm interested in generating a list of all fields with a column highlighting the feature that contains the field base setting and another column highlighting the field instance feature, (if the field is defined in a feature).

Something like this...

```
Field Name     |   Field Base Defined In  | Field Instance Defined In
field_subtitle |   mysite_shared_fields   | blog_story_feature
field_other    |   mysite_shared_fields   | blog_story_feature
```

Has anyone attempted this? Or can anyone suggest a solution.

Comment: Have you looked at `{field_config}` table? And [`hook_field_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7)? It should give you idea where you don't have this data, and where you can have some of it. Not all, mind you.

Comment: Thanks Molot, this is useful for getting the initial list.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful functions /snippets below

```
field_info_instances();

$features_map = features_get_component_map();

$features_map['field_base'];
$features_map['field_instance'];
return;
foreach (field_info_fields() as $key => $field) {
  $base = isset($features_map['field_base'][$key]) ? join(',',$features_map['field_base'][$key]) : 'NOT IN A FEATURE!';
  $instance = 'todo';
  $rows[] = array($key, $base, $instance);
}
print theme('table', array('header' => array('machine_name', 'base', 'instance'), 'rows' => $rows));
return;

$components = features_get_components();
$field_base_component = $components['field_base'];
features_include_defaults($field_base_component);
$field_instance_components = $components['field_instance'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For older sites where field instances and sites are not stored separately in features

```
$features_map = features_get_component_map(NULL, TRUE);

// loop through field instances, this gives a deep array of
// content types...
foreach (field_info_instances() as $type => $bundles) {
  // ...containing bundles...
  foreach ($bundles as $bundle => $field) {
    // ...containing fields
    foreach($field as $field_name => $field_info) {
       // the key for the feature is...
       $features_instance_key = $type . '-' . $bundle . '-' . $field_name;  
       if ( isset($features_map['field'][$features_instance_key]) ) {
         $in_feature = join(',', $features_map['field'][$features_instance_key]);
       }
       else {
         $in_feature = 'NOT IN A FEATURE';
       }
       $instance_map[$field_name] = $in_feature;
    }
  }
}

foreach (field_info_fields() as $key => $field) {
  $rows[] = array($key, $instance_map[$key]);
}
print theme('table', array('header' => array('machine_name', 'feature'), 'rows' => $rows));
return;
```